# Length of array of json objects

Tags: javascript

example:

```
var birds = [{
    Name: 'Bald Eagle1',
    Type: 'Hawk',
    ScientificName: 'Haliaeetus Leucocephalus'
},{
    Name: 'Bald Eagle2',
    Type: 'Hawk',
    ScientificName: 'Haliaeetus Leucocephalus'
},{
    Name: 'Bald Eagle3',
    Type: 'Hawk',
    ScientificName: 'Haliaeetus Leucocephalus'
}]
```

i need to find the length of every object in javascript. In this case the result should be 3.
I tried with birds.length, Object.keys(birds).length and no results. Please help me

Comment: Interesting, because console.log(birds.length) will definitely show `3` here.

Comment: Are you looking for the length of the array **birds**?

Comment: I am pushing into array declared like this : var array = []; responses from get method, and the result i am reciving is like the one in the question. When i try to get the lenght it returns 0, and when i console.log(array) i see that there are objects in there

Answer (score 0):

If all elements have the same number keys, you could just check the number of keys for the **first element** using:

`Object.keys(birds[0]).length`

This also assumes that there is at least one element in the array.

Answer (score 0):

The following will map the list of objects to a list of lengths (in terms of attributes):

```
var lenghts = birds.map(bird => Object.keys(bird).length)
```

If you know that all have the same length you can just sample one:

```
var length = Object.keys(birds[0]).length
```

To clarify, if you just want the number of objects in that array you can just do:

```
var numberOfBirds = birds.length
```

Comment: I think you're missing a `.length`, this will return a list of strings. i.e `var lenghts = birds.map(bird => Object.keys(bird))` will return a `Array(3), Array(3), Array(3)]`